# How do I rename lots of files changing the same filename element for each in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to rename a load of files (I count over 200) that either have the company name in the filename, or in the text contents. I basically need to change any references to "company" to "newcompany", maintaining capitalisation where applicable (ie "Company becomes Newcompany", "company" becomes "newcompany"). I need to do this recursively.

Because the name could occur pretty much anywhere I've not been able to find example code anywhere that meets my requirements. It could be any of these examples, or more:

```
company.jpg
company.php
company.Class.php
company.Company.php
companysomething.jpg
```

Hopefully you get the idea. I not only need to do this with filenames, but also the contents of text files, such as HTML and PHP scripts. I'm presuming this would be a second command, but I'm not entirely sure what.

I've searched the codebase and found nearly 2000 mentions of the company name in nearly 300 files, so I don't fancy doing it manually.

Please help! :)

Comment: retitled and removed recursion.  This is not really about recursion (all multiple operations are not recursion!), it's about - see new title.

Comment: Sorry, it appeared that when Googling the problem a LOT of people were asking the same question. It's recursively going through all directories, in the same way as chmod -R or chown -R do, so it seemed like the obvious title. The files are not all in the same directory, but they are all in either this directory or child directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` has powerful looping and substitution capabilities:

```
for filename in `find /root/of/where/files/are -name *company*`; do
    mv $filename ${filename/company/newcompany}
done
for filename in `find /root/of/where/files/are -name *Company*`; do
    mv $filename ${filename/Company/Newcompany}
done
```

Comment: I may have made a hash of that somehow, not sure. I get this:

syntax error near unexpected token `mv'

Comment: I had a missing `;`, fixed now

Comment: Magic! That works. Now I just need to sort the contents of the files where there are references to company and Company. Simple and effective that one, thank you

Comment: I found what I thought was a solution to editing the content of the files as well:
    find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/company/newcompany/' {} \;
I think I may have missed something out from that though as it only seemed to replace the first instance in a file. Otherwise that filled in the rest of the blanks, along with your excellent and simple script. Thanks

Comment: try changing `s/company/newcompany/` to `s/company/newcompany/g` - `g` is for global

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look at `man rename` an extremely powerful perl-utility for, well, renaming files.

Standard syntax is

```
rename 's/\.htm$/\.html/' *.htm
```

the clever part is that the tool accept any perl-regexp as a pattern for a filename to be changed.

you might want to run it with the `-n` switch which will make the tool to only report what it would have changed.

Can't figure out a nice way to keep the capitalization right now, but since you already can search through the filestructure, issue several `rename` with different capitalization until all files are changed.

To loop through all files below current folder and to search for a particular string, you can use

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n -i STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR /dev/null {} \;
```

The output from that command can be directed to a file (after some filtering to just extract the file names of the files that need to be changed).

```
find . /type ... > files_to_operate_on
```

Then wrap that in a `while read` loop and do some perl-magic for inplace-replacement

```
while read file
do
    perl -pi -e 's/stringtoreplace/replacementstring/g' $file
done < files_to_operate_on
```

Answer (score 1):

For the file and directory names, use `for`, `find`, `mv` and `sed`.

For each path (`f`) that has `company` in the name, rename it (`mv`) from `f` to the new name where `company` is replaced by `newcompany`.

```
for f in `find -name '*company*'` ; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/company/nemcompany/`" ; done
```

For the file contents, use `find`, `xargs` and `sed`.

For every file, change `company` by `newcompany` in its content, keeping original file with extension `.backup`.

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i .bakup 's/company/newcompany/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few right ways to recursively process files. Here's one:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
    newfile="${file//Company/Newcompany}"
    newfile="${newfile//company/newcompany}"
    mv -f "$file" "$newfile"
done < <(find /basedir/ -iname '*company*' -print0)
```

This will work with all possible file names, not just ones without whitespace in them.

Presumes bash.

For changing the contents of files I would advise caution because a blind replacement within a file could break things if the file is not plain text. That said, `sed` was made for this sort of thing.

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
    sed -i '' -e 's/Company/Newcompany/g;s/company/newcompany/g'"$file"
done < <(find /basedir/ -iname '*company*' -print0)
```

For this run I recommend adding some additional switches to `find` to limit the files it will process, perhaps

```
find /basedir/ \( -iname '*company*' -and \( -iname '*.txt' -or -ianem '*.html' \) \) -print0
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a sed solution that I found elsewhere in the end, but it seemed to only replace the first occurrence. Had to either keep running it or finish it off manually. Did most for me though, which was nice :) This was the command: find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/company/newcompany/' {} \;

Comment: @AntTheKnee: A `sed` `s///` expression will only replace the first instance. You need to add the `g` ("global") option to make it replace more than one instance per line, e.g. `s///g`, as you see in my example.